# C++ Transparent window

Tags: c++, winapi, window

I would like to know how to make a transparent program in C++, what I mean by this is that all you are  able to see is the content of the window (text/content). I would also prefer to not use libraries like Qt, and to only use default libraries (and SDL/OpenGL if needed).

I am not after a console, I want a window which I can display images and text on.

System: Windows 7

Comment: You mean you don't want a console? What exactly are you asking?

Comment: No, I don't want a console, I want an external window which I can display text/images on and is transparent

Comment: Specifying which platform you are writing for may help.

Comment: See the docs for `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` and `UpdateLayeredWindow` as they are the key functions.

Comment: Please read [my comment to the answer you've received](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870809/c-transparent-window#comment26160415_17907820) and update your question accordingly. Which do you want?

Comment: What do you mean? I have specified what I am after in my question: A completely invisible window except for content (lines, text, etc)

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like:

`SetLayeredWindowAttributes(GetActiveWindow(), NULL, Alpha, LWA_ALPHA);`

In this case `Alpha` is varaible [0; 255] which determines how much transparency will be. Also you need to check if returned value is `TRUE`.

Comment: This will make the *entire window* transparent, including its content. Its not clear from the question if this is what is wanted. It sounds like he wants the window chrome to go away and leave just the content.

Answer (score 0):

I have a project on github that creates a Semi-Transparent Window with a few Custom

Push buttons -> https://github.com/xx4g/twlekezexe

There is a file transparentwindowbuilder.cpp it contains the below function.

I had better luck with updatelayeredwindow for rendering.

Usually i use setlayeredwindow when I just want an invisible window.

example :

WndProc: It's important to note we have to send the WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN message ourselves:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)                  /* handle the messages */
    {
    case WM_MOVE:
        UpdatePosProc();
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:/* the window was destroyed */
        PostQuitMessage(0);       /* send a WM_QUIT to the message queue */
        break;
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:/* the left mouse button was clicked */
        mouseHit = true;
        ::PostMessage(hwnd,WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN,HTCAPTION,lParam);  /* send a HTCAPTION to the message queue */
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    default:                      /* for messages that we don't deal with */
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

//In main.cpp somewhere
     hWndParent = MakeTransparentWindowProc(hThisInstance, SW_HIDE, L"back1.png", L"PNGDialog1", L"winexe", width, height, WindowProcedure, false,HWND_DESKTOP);
//transparentwindowbuilder.cpp  
    HWND MakeTransparentWindowProc (HINSTANCE hThisInstance,
   

int nCmdShow,
    const wchar_t* ImagePng1, /* This is the PNG image path */
    const wchar_t* windowClassName1,/* This is the class name */
    const wchar_t* windowName1, /* This is the application name */
    int width, /* This is the window width */
    int height,/* This is the window height */
    WNDPROC windocProcedure,
bool toolwindow,HWND Parent)
{
    /* Start GDIPlus */
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusStartupToken;  /* GDIPlus Startup Token */
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiInput;
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusStartupToken, &gdiInput, NULL);


    /* Make a transparent Window*/

    /* Local Variables*/

    HWND hwnd;               /* This is the handle for our window */
     /* Make Transparent Window */
    auto result = makeTransParentWindow(hThisInstance,  /* the hInstance, Should use WinMains HInstance */
        hwnd,  /* This is the handle for our window */
        nCmdShow,  /* The show Window Flag */
        ImagePng1,  /* The path to the Image File */
        windocProcedure, /* The pointer to the window procedure */
        windowClassName1, /* The name of the NEw class to create */
        width,/* The length */
        height,/* The width */
        windowName1, toolwindow, Parent);

    /* Shut down GDIPlus*/
    Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusStartupToken);

    return result ? hwnd : nullptr;
}
bool makeTransParentWindow(HINSTANCE& hThisInstance, HWND& hWnd, int& nCmdShow, const wchar_t*& imagePath, WNDPROC lpfnWndProc, const wchar_t*& szClassName, int Width, int Height, const wchar_t*& szWindowName,bool toolwindow,HWND Parent)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wincl;        /* Data structure for the windowclass */

    if (!RegisterWindowClass(wincl, hThisInstance, szClassName, lpfnWndProc)) return false;

    /* The class is registered, let's create the program*/
    if (!CreateWindowPane(hWnd, szClassName, Width, Height, hThisInstance, szWindowName, toolwindow, Parent)) return false;

    /* Make the window visible on the screen */
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);

    RenderWindow(hWnd, imagePath);

    return true;
}

void RenderWindow(HWND& hWnd, const wchar_t*& imagePath)
{
    RECT wndRect;

    ::GetWindowRect(hWnd, &wndRect);

    SIZE wndSize = { wndRect.right - wndRect.left,wndRect.bottom - wndRect.top };

    DrawSizedWindow(hWnd, wndSize, imagePath);
}

void DrawSizedWindow(HWND& hWnd, SIZE& wndSize, const wchar_t*& imagePath)
{
    HDC hdc = ::GetDC(hWnd);

    HDC memDC = ::CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);

    HBITMAP memBitmap = ::CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, wndSize.cx, wndSize.cy);

    SelectAndDrawObject(memDC, memBitmap, imagePath, wndSize);

    HDC screenDC = GetDC(NULL);

    BlendLayeredWindow(hWnd, screenDC, wndSize, memDC);

    CleanUpObjects(memDC, memBitmap, hWnd, screenDC);
}

void SelectAndDrawObject(HDC& memDC, const HBITMAP& memBitmap, const wchar_t*& imagePath, SIZE& wndSize)
{
    ::SelectObject(memDC, memBitmap);

    ::DrawGdiImage(imagePath, memDC, wndSize);
}

void BlendLayeredWindow(HWND& hWnd, const HDC& screenDC, SIZE& wndSize, const HDC& memDC)
{
    POINT ptSrc = { 0,0 };

    BLENDFUNCTION blendFunction;

    ::SetBlendFunctionSetiings(blendFunction);

    ::UpdateLayeredWindow(hWnd, screenDC, &ptSrc, &wndSize, memDC, &ptSrc, 0, &blendFunction, 2);
}

void CleanUpObjects(const HDC& memDC, const HBITMAP& memBitmap, HWND& hWnd, const HDC& screenDC)
{
    ::DeleteDC(memDC);

    ::DeleteObject(memBitmap);

    ::ReleaseDC(hWnd, screenDC);
}

void DrawGdiImage(const wchar_t*& imagePath, const HDC& memDC, SIZE& wndSize)
{
    Gdiplus::Image image(imagePath);
    Gdiplus::Graphics graphics(memDC);
    graphics.DrawImage(&image, 0, 0, wndSize.cx, wndSize.cy);
}

bool CreateWindowPane(HWND& hWnd, const wchar_t*& szClassName, int Width, int Height, HINSTANCE& hThisInstance, const wchar_t*& windowName,bool toolwindow,HWND Owner)
{
    if (toolwindow)
    {
        hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
            WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_NOACTIVATE,                   /* Extended possibilites for variation */
            szClassName,         /* Classname */
            windowName,       /* Title Text */
            WS_POPUPWINDOW | WS_CHILD, /* default window */
            CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* Windows decides the position */
            CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* where the window ends up on the screen */
            Width,                 /* The programs width */
            Height,                 /* and height in pixels */
            Owner,        /* The window is a child-window to desktop */
            NULL,                /* No menu */
            hThisInstance,       /* Program Instance handler */
            NULL                 /* No Window Creation data */
        );

    }
    else
    {
        hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
            WS_EX_LAYERED,                   /* Extended possibilites for variation */
            szClassName,         /* Classname */
            windowName,       /* Title Text */
            WS_POPUPWINDOW, /* default window */
            CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* Windows decides the position */
            CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* where the window ends up on the screen */
            Width,                 /* The programs width */
            Height,                 /* and height in pixels */
            HWND_DESKTOP,        /* The window is a child-window to desktop */
            NULL,                /* No menu */
            hThisInstance,       /* Program Instance handler */
            NULL                 /* No Window Creation data */
        );
    }
    return hWnd != nullptr;
}

bool RegisterWindowClass(WNDCLASSEX& wincl, HINSTANCE& hThisInstance, const wchar_t*& szClassName, const WNDPROC& lpfnWndProc)
{
    /* The Window structure */
    wincl.hInstance = hThisInstance;
    wincl.lpszClassName = szClassName;
    wincl.lpfnWndProc = lpfnWndProc;      /* This function is called by windows */
    wincl.style = CS_DBLCLKS;                 /* Catch double-clicks */
    wincl.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    /* Use default icon and mouse-pointer */
    wincl.hIcon = LoadIcon(hThisInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_WINEXE));
    wincl.hIconSm = LoadIcon(hThisInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_WINEXE));
    wincl.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wincl.lpszMenuName = NULL;                 /* No menu */
    wincl.cbClsExtra = 0;                      /* No extra bytes after the window class */
    wincl.cbWndExtra = 0;                      /* structure or the window instance */
                                               /* Use Windows's default colour as the background of the window */
    wincl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_BACKGROUND;

    /* Register the window class, and if it fails quit the program */
    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wincl))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

void SetBlendFunctionSetiings(BLENDFUNCTION& blendFunction)
{
    blendFunction.AlphaFormat = AC_SRC_ALPHA;
    blendFunction.BlendFlags = 0;
    blendFunction.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
    blendFunction.SourceConstantAlpha = 220;
}
```